# Access user information in azure web site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, active-directory

I have enabled the authentication in my azure web application using Google+ as the provider following the steps mentioned at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication/

I have to restrict access to the logged in user to selected pages in my website. 
How can it be done?

for ex: If I have 2 pages View Products and Edit Products. Only a particular user should be allowed to access Edit Products page and all users should be able to access View Products page. Is this possible?

Also how can I access the name of the user and other basic information like email of the user that has logged in?

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted is about authentication. But what you want to accomplish is about user role management.

Please check this link:

[Working with User Roles](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc)